# Iterating through dataframe and extract special characters

Tags: python, loops, dataframe, extract

```
school_earning_premium_hourly   dips_cert_earning_premium_weekly 
5.785123966942149\B             110.7438016528926\I
```

I have multiple columns (2 of them are above) in my dataframe. I need a way to iterate through all of the columns and extract the unwanted characters.

If i were to clean each column individually, I would use

```
data['school_earning_premium_hourly'] =
data.school_earning_premium_hourly.str.replace(
                    '[\\|A|B|C|D|E|F|G|H|I|J|K|L|M|N|O|P|Q|R|S|T|U|V|W|X|Y|Z]','')
```

But now I need to find a way to iterate over every single column(I have 103) and remove the characters as well as change the objects/strings to floats in order to plot the data.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the column names to loop through them all and do what you described:

```
for i in range(len(data.columns)):
    col = data.columns[i]
    data[col] = data[col].str.replace('[\|A|B|C|D|E|F|G|H|I|J|K|L|M|N|O|P|Q|R|S|T|U|V|W|X|Y|Z]','')
```